# ngrx updateOne change ids array sorting

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have an index of Invoices loaded from API to the NGRX Store,
When the user enters a single Invoice it updates the full details from the API.

**the Issue is that the index order changed when I user Ngrx `updateOne`**
I find that the ids array moves the entity to the front when updating it.

This issue is known and should be solved on older Ngrx version (v10):
https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/571

**I'm using Ngrx version 12**

[image: When loading index]

[image: after updateOne]

[image: Index problem]

Sort part on State

```
export const invoicesAdapter: EntityAdapter<InvoiceInterface> = createEntityAdapter<InvoiceInterface>({
  selectId: customizedInvoiceId,
  sortComparer: sortByCreatedAt 
});

export function customizedInvoiceId(a: InvoiceInterface): string {
  return a.id;
}

export function sortByCreatedAt(a: InvoiceInterface, b: InvoiceInterface): number {
  return a.createdBy?.toLocaleString().localeCompare(b.createdBy?.toLocaleString());
}
```

updateOne on Reducer

```js
const _invoicesReducer = createReducer(
  initialInvoicesState,
  on(addInvoiceSuccess, (state, action) => {
    return invoicesAdapter.addOne(action.invoice, state);
  }),
  on(updateInvoiceSuccess, (state, action) => {
    return invoicesAdapter.updateOne(action.invoice, state);
  }),

...
```

Angular and Ngrx Packages

```json
"dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~12.2.0",
        "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.0",
        "@angular/common": "~12.2.0",
        "@angular/core": "~12.2.0",
        "@angular/forms": "~12.2.0",
        "@angular/material": "^12.2.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.0",
        "@angular/router": "~12.2.0",
        "@angular/service-worker": "~12.2.0",
        "@ngrx/effects": "^12.5.1",
        "@ngrx/entity": "^12.5.1",
        "@ngrx/router-store": "^12.5.1",
        "@ngrx/store": "^12.5.1",
        "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^12.5.1",
        "@capacitor/android": "3.1.1",
...
```

Comment: Library uses `updatedIndexes.push(index);` (updated your github issue). Should be an easy PR fix if behavior is unintended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue was on the sort function

```js
export function sortByCreatedAt(a: InvoiceInterface, b: InvoiceInterface): number {
  return a.createdBy?.toLocaleString().localeCompare(b.createdBy?.toLocaleString());
}
```

```js
export function sortByCreatedAt(a: InvoiceInterface, b: InvoiceInterface): number {
  return b.createdAt?.toLocaleString().localeCompare(a.createdAt?.toLocaleString());
}
```

were the `createdBy` is an object

Comment: got the same with rtx
changing boolean attribute causes ids array reordering
so I've changed
`sortComparer: (one, another) => one.online === another.online ? another.id - one.id : Number(another.online) - Number(one.online)`
to just
`sortComparer: (one, another) => another.id - one.id,`
and put sorting in component